# How do I fix the Spring XML validation in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-integration, xsd-validation

I am getting a "false positive" error in a Spring XML file....

Expected behavior: The inbound channel adapter element with header-mapper of DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper validates properly in IntelliJ

Actual behavior: IntelliJ reports that the header-mapper is not of type HeaderMapper

There was an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2971) that was fixed in 3.0 but it seems like my IntelliJ is validating the below applicationContext.xml against an old version of the amqp schema. How do I refresh it?

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

   <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
           channel="ch1" queue-names="queue"
           connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" error-channel="errorChannel"
           header-mapper="allHeadersMapper" concurrent-consumers="1" />
```

Edit: Was found in 14.1.5. Upgraded to 2016.3.4 on Linux and reproduced.
Reproduced with simple code at https://github.com/dcw312/intellij-validation-error. IntelliJ issue created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167842

Comment: M-m-m. Upgrade IDEA? 14.1 is pretty old already...

Comment: Well, anyway this is just only ide issue. There are many other flaws around XML config support, as well as Java config. At runtime that all should be fine

Comment: I upgraded to IDEA 2016.3.4 and the issue was not resolved.

Comment: Well, maybe you use Community edition, not Ultimate...

Comment: Hm, yes. Sorry. Now I see the same problem. As I said: this is just IDE issue. Never mind. Of course, you can go to IDEA tracker and try to discuss with their developers what's going on. And no: I don't know any IDEA config to tackle on the matter.